# Data Validation Delimited List

Tags: excel, excel-formula, validation

I am trying to use the following formula for data validation:

```
=IF(F6="","",IF(F6="Yes",Lookups!$B$2,Lookups!$E$2:$E$8))
```

However I am met with an error stating that 'the list source must be a delimited list, or a reference to a single row or column'.

I can't figure out what the issue is, as if I replace any of the ranges with text (such as "Yes" or "No") it works fine and the referenced ranges also seem fine on their own!

Comment: What is the other option for F6 (e.g. what would cause the list to come from `Lookups!$E$2:$E$8`?) What is in B1 and what is in E1?

Comment: The only options for F6 are Yes, No or left blank

Answer (score 0):

You can populate your data validation list by referencing a dynamic named range.

1. Put *Yes* in Lookups!B1.
2. Put *No* in Lookups!E1.
3. Select  Lookups!B2:E8 and launch Formulas ► Defined names ► Name Manager.
4. Create a new named range called *my_vList* using `=index(Lookups!$B$2:$E$8, , MATCH(Sheet1!$F$6, Lookups!$B$1:$E$1, 0))` as the *Refers to:*.
5. Go back to the Data Validation for Sheet1!F6 and change the *Source:* of the list to *=my_vList*.

The list will be populated with B2 if F6 is *Yes*, E2:E8 if F6 is *No* and (for all intents and purposes) disabled if F6 is blank.

Comment: Thanks for this, however there a couple of issues with implementing this solution. Firstly, I can't get it to work - I've followed the steps exactly and am told that 'the source currently evaluates an error'. Furthermore, I'd like to copy this data validation formula to several hundred cells, and would rather not create a large number of named ranges (each of which refer to a cell different than F6).